# Remove the last element from a multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem:

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((1,3,3))
x
```

which leads me to a multidimensional array with 3 elements:

```
    array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]])
```

How can I create a new array with just the first two elements out of each dimension?
So that it looks like this output:

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [3, 4],
        [6, 7]]])
```

Comment: If you want just the _"just the first two elements out of each dimension"_ your expected answer should be `array([[[0, 1], [3, 4]]])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is just list slicing!

`list[a:b]` >> start from a-th element and go up to b-th element

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(9).reshape((1,3,3))

def my_slicing (inp, shape):
    inp = list(inp)
    if type(shape) is tuple: shape=list(shape)
    if len(shape)>1:
        for i,v in enumerate(inp[:shape[0]]):
            inp[i]=my_resize(v,shape[1:])
    else:
        return inp[:shape[0]]
    return np.array(inp[:shape[0]])
        
    pass
print(x)

print(my_slicing(x, (1,3,2))) # custom slicing function

print(x[:1,:3,:2]) # numpy slicing function
```

```
[[[0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]
  [6 7 8]]]
[[[0 1]
  [3 4]
  [6 7]]]
[[[0 1]
  [3 4]
  [6 7]]]
```

Comment: What's the point of the `my_slicing()` function when you've shown that standard numpy slicing works?

Answer (score 2):

You can access those elements using array slicing.

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((1,3,3))    
x[:, :, :2]
```

Comment: Don't know why the other answer was the accepted one - **this is the correct answer** +1. Or `x[:2, :2, :2]` if they really want _"just the first two elements out of each dimension"_.